# MATLAB output array

Tags: matlab, array, simulink

I'm a beginner and I got a Script and I have to out put RES{1} and RES{2}

```
RES{ii,1} = measure;
RES{ii,2} = measure_filter;
```

measure and measure_filter will be filled before. But I don't know how to output the result.

Can someone help me out?

PS: is this the right place to ask such a question?

Comment: What you mean by "output the result"? The way this code is written, you are creating a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), where the `{ii,1}` element is the output of the `measure` function and the `{ii,2}` element is the output of the `measure_filter` function.

Comment: I wan't to look what is inside the array. How do I have to code it?

Comment: double click the variable you want to look in the Workspace and you will be able to see the variable contents in the Variable Editor. Alternatively, any variable you type in a m file, if you don't add the `;` character at the end of the instruction, MATLAB will automatically display the variable contens in the Command Window.